# How can join fields in a field one2many in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to join two fields in a field one2many like the photo
[image]

is it posible make this?

Comment: you have a parent object link on the line object. So either you can do with it while creating the record or make the computing field.

Comment: Use computed field on order lines model. Define char field and its compute method to join order_id.name and order_id.diario into this new field. Dont forget to set @api.depends to order_id, so the value si recalculatted.